# $f\circ f=f^2$ Solution

Tags: functions, relations, inverse, function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Define a function $f: X\to X$
such that $f$ is not equal to $Ix$ and is one to one. Find $f\circ f=f^2$ and $f$'s inverse.

Comment: So you're looking for a bijection $f:X\to X$ such that $f(f(x))=(f(x))^2$?

Comment: Yes, however, I'm also given this X={1,2,3,4}. I keep getting f(x)=x^2 :/

Comment: In agreement with @Dave, I find your question ambiguous. Has a function $f$ been given to you beforehand? If $f^2$ means what you get by multiplying values, then $f^2$ is not a map from $X$ to $X$. Or, yet again, is $f$ to be an unspecified function $X\to X$, and you’re being asked to explain what $f\circ f$ is. This is the only reasonable meaning of $f^2$ as a function $X\to X$, in which case you would not be being asked to *solve* an equation at all. So if this was a homework assignment, please quote it literally.

Comment: I have an exam tomorrow, and this is a question in the book that I have a doubt with, I'll put in the exact question in the question above, please see.

Comment: What about $f(x)=1$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk That's not a bijection, thus not invertible.

Comment: I've modified it. f(x)=1 is an Identity, that's not allowed.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense then.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want to find a $f$ such that : $f$ is a bijection, $f(f) = f^2$  and then you want to find $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @RamitSawhney Does your book use the notation $f^2$ for $f \circ f$ composition?

Comment: As I understand you just have to make up some bijective function $X\to X$, compute it's composition with itself and it's inverse?

Comment: Ohhh... does $f^2$ mean $f(f(x))$?

Comment: The book doesn't use $f^2$ for $f(f(x))$ anywhere, but I think what Henrik is saying only seems correct, in any other case the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That $2$ has nothing to do with *multiplying*  It' just means composing.  $f\circ f = f^2$ and $f\circ f \circ f = f^3$ etc.  the actually squaring wouldn't make any sense as $3^2 = 9 \not \in X$ $4^2 = 16 \not \in X$ so $(f)^2 = f*f: X \not \rightarrow X$.

Comment: If that's the case, you could define a piecewise function that maps one element to the next one.

Comment: @fleablood `squaring wouldn't make any sense` That's not entirely true, and it's part of what entertained the confusion. For example $f(x)=1$ *does* satisfy $f(f(x)) = (f(x))^2$ as pointed out already.

Comment: @dxiv f(x) = 1 is not one to one by any stretch of the imagination.  If f is a one to one there is an $f(x) = 3$ but $f(x)^2 = 9 = f\circ f(x)$ is not possible.

Comment: @fleablood Such a bijection does not exist, indeed, but your previous comment did not emphasize that point or, in fact, mention bijectivity at all. I was just saying that the blanket statement `squaring wouldn't make any sense` is not unconditionally true. For example a question like "*How many functions $f$ exist such that $f(f(x)) = (f(x))^2$*" would be entirely legitimate.

Comment: Um.. the op mentioned 1z1.  I took that to be exceedingly important enough to go without saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $24=4!$ injective, surjective maps from $X$ to $X$. These are usually called permutations of $X$. You are being asked to find one of the $23$ maps different from the identity, and name it $f$. The second part of the question is to find what permutation $f\circ f$ is. (This permutation is most often denoted $f^2$.) The third part of the question is to find the permutation that is inverse to $f$.

Comment: Yeah, just got confused in the notation of f^2. Sorry about that, thankyou so much

Comment: I’m glad I could help. It’s easy to miss the point of a question like this.

Comment: +1 for an accepted answer that essentially restates the question to the point it becomes obvious.

Comment: But the pedagogical point is that when you’re new to a field, nothing is obvious. And it’s amazingly easy to misinterpret almost any new concept.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right:

A identity mapping $f$ defined by:
$f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) =3, f(4) = 4$

This is a bijection, $f^2 = f$ and $f^{-1} = f$ is what we start from.
Now, we just need to change $f$ a bit to not make it an identity mapping.

Simplest way to do that is to mix it up by shifting the outputs by one ie:

$f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, f(3) =4, f(4) = 1$
Then $f^2(x) = f(x+1)$ and $f^{-1}(x) = f^3(x)$

Comment: No, the question excludes the identity permutation.

Comment: @Lubin I see, changed the answer a bit then.